# DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a Navigation drawer, but I keep getting this error.
I saw the similar questions but did not work for me. I have the following layout activity_main2.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

On my activity_main2.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    initView();
    if (toolbar != null) {
        //toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    initDrawer();
}

private void initView() {
    leftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    navigationDrawerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leftSliderData);
    leftDrawerList.setAdapter(navigationDrawerAdapter);
    leftDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 1){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initDrawer() {
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? On runtime or in Android Studio? Are you using the latest support library?

Comment: using Android Studio and got the runtime error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

My DrawerLayout was inside a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/abohawawallpapersqr"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

        <!-- ...... -->
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I solved the problem by changing the `layout_height="wrap_content"` to `layout_height="match_parent"` of `LinearLayout`.So the code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/abohawawallpapersqr"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Answer (score 24):

This can also happen because of the new `ConstraintLayout`. Make sure the drawer layout isn't in the hierarchy of `ConstraintLayout`.

**Edit**

Make sure you are using right constraints to ensure that height is not 0dp when using constraint layout

Comment: What'd you prefer instead? I replace it with LinearLayout and I get: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.LinearLayout

Comment: You're absolutely right. RelativeLayout worked best for me here.

Comment: @VipulKumar You should set both width and height of DrawerLayout to 0dp in ConstraintLayout. If only set height to 0dp, width to match_parent, which will cause this problem.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001482/drawerlayout-inside-constaintlayout-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-drawer

Comment: @user175257 just tried out that solution and it worked for me. Would recommend trying this to those having issues with DrawerLayout combined with ConstraintLayout

Comment: Please see other solutions about how to use DrawerLayout in ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 23):

For those who still have an exception, ensure your `DrawerLayout`'s height is `match_parent`

Answer (score 15):

Make sure your activity is not a "Dialog" activity, check in the manifest. I made this mistake and got the error.

Comment: You saved my butt.  I was convinced this was related to ConstraintLayout, but it was a good old Dialog themed Activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This can also happen if you have set `layout_width` to `wrap_content`. In my case it was solved by setting width to `match_parent`. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

use this ...

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context) {
       super(context);
}
public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
 }
     public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
      MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
      heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
      MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

was solved my problem by creating the activity like below;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still get this Exception make sure that your activity is full Screen defined 
In Manifest u can do in `Activity`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.FullScreen"
```

Or define this in `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: This was it for me, while trying to convert my old application to be more Dark theme friendly, [as per Android instructions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme). In my case my style was `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">`.  And then, magically the 'measurespec' errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

Even I tried the Drawer's layout_height = "match_parent" but also java threw an error, so I just restarted android studio it worked no errors were found

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set Exactly measurements explicitly always like below:

```
public class MyDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    public MyDrawerLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, I set a custom dialog theme to the activity instead of a custom activity theme:

```
activity.setTheme(R.style.StyledDialogTheme);
```

After i corrected this, it workes again.