# How do I place a ScrollView in the code below?

Tags: android

Below is my XML code. Where do I place a scrollview attribute on the whole screen because some of my view does not show when I switch to landscape view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">







    <!--  whole linearlayout vertical begin tag   -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCalendar"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
            <DatePicker
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:id="@+id/button" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFollowUpRequest"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBookingRequest"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOccupancy"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />



        </LinearLayout>






    </LinearLayout>     <!-- Whole linear Vertical layout close tag    -->



    <!-- Whole linear Horizontal layout begin tag    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/border">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Follow Up"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textViewFollowUp" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/buttonFollowUp" />




        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/border">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Events Today"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textViewEventsToday" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/buttonEventsToday" />




        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/border">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Bookings Today"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textViewBookingsToday" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/buttonBookingsToday" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- Whole linear horizontal layout close tag    -->


<!--  linear vertical layout for drawer tag start   -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/maintcont"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
            android:entries="@array/planets"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#fff"
            >

        </ListView>



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!--  linear vertical layout for drawer tag close   -->




</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the normal view

[image: Normal view]

Land scape view

[image: LandScape View]

What I want to achieve is to have a scrollview on the whole view so I can scroll down to see all views on landscape. Please note I am using a menu drawer layout is the last on my XML. if try placing the scroll view on before the Relative layout, I get the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
```

And if I place after the relative layout, it lunches but do not scroll.

I have been able to resolve the scroll but this is how my drawer is showing. Intercepting my main view
Here is the screen shot
[image: screen shot]

And here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/maintcont"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
            android:entries="@array/planets"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#fff"
            >

        </ListView>



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>














 <ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>


 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">












    <!--  whole linearlayout vertical begin tag   -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCalendar"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
            <DatePicker
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:id="@+id/button" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFollowUpRequest"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBookingRequest"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOccupancy"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />



        </LinearLayout>






    </LinearLayout>     <!-- Whole linear Vertical layout close tag    -->









    <!-- Whole linear Horizontal layout begin tag    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/border">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Follow Up"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textViewFollowUp" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/buttonFollowUp" />




        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/border">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Events Today"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textViewEventsToday" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/buttonEventsToday" />




        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/border">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Bookings Today"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/textViewBookingsToday" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_buttom_margin"
                android:id="@+id/buttonBookingsToday" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

```
</ScrollView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please what could be wrong.

Comment: Did you try and wrap the scroll view around "whole linearlayout vertical begin tag"?

Comment: Please just go through my code @cYrixmorten I am new in android and please tell me where to place the linear layout before the scroll view

Answer (score 1):

You can put scroll view just after the `<RelativeLayout..>`. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/someid">

<RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--  whole linearlayout vertical begin tag   -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried that often a time and the error I get is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child`

Comment: That is because Scroll view can contain only one child. You can add one more `<RelativeLayout>` just after the `<ScrollView>` and close it at the end just before closing the `</ScrollView>` so that everything is contained inside the `<RelativeLayout>` which is now the child of `<ScrollView>`.

Comment: Please check my updated code..I do not know where is wrong and my screen shot too

Comment: For the DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY error check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746072/drawerlayout-must-be-measured-with-measurespec-exactly-error