# Application crashes on building AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

My android app crashes after i build (create) my costum AlertDialog.
How i creating AlertDialog:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View view_ = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dictionary_popup_main, null);
            builder.setView(view_);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

This error i getting:

```
10-11 22:31:18.296 26830-26830/blah.quake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1041)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:713)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:783)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1421)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:579)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2155)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4218)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please, help me, i'm tryed to search any answers for my errors, but a lot of people write "this" in a first line (while creating AlertDialog), and i don't found any people with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share R.layout.dictionary_popup_main file content? The error seems to be in DrawerLayout code.

Comment: The context is wrong where are you using it, in activity or fragment try get activity() or get context()

Comment: check this question and answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746072/drawerlayout-must-be-measured-with-measurespec-exactly-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter, i already found a answer:
just need to make code like this:

```
        View view_ = (View)findViewById(R.id.dictl_l);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.l_word) + main)
                .setView(someLayout);
        AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
        dlg.show();
```