# Program always stopping after making Side Bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating an app that displays side bar below my toolbar and here is my code.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/darkgray"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/darkgray"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is my java

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_felcosfafield, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("Test");
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

and here are the gradles depedencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

I just follow the instructions from a tutorial but when I try it the apps suddenly crashes and also I found an error here

`DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.`

What are the problems? and How can I fix it?

Comment: You can take a look on this answer, hope of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746072/drawerlayout-must-be-measured-with-measurespec-exactly-error?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746072/drawerlayout-must-be-measured-with-measurespec-exactly-error)

Comment: tried that but no luck

Comment: im new to android prog. and also seen that links too but cannot follow it

Answer (score 0):

Use Lineralayout as a parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
<!-- ...... -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If i make that the sidebar goes next to the textview which is my title